# How to bind click event to relevant element in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have my list of menu.

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and I create another nav, that is nav2.

```
<div class="nav2">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

when the time I click the under nav menu. The event of `nav2` menu will click. How can I do that in jquery? I try to use bind in jquery but i don't get the idea on how to do it. I have this code for finding and event. But I'm confuse on how I connect it to `nav2`.

```
var banlenght = $('.nav').find('li');
banlenght.each(function(){
  var ban = $(this);
  ban.click(function(){});
});
```

Comment: Means you want to create common function/Event for both the list click events??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get index of clicked item in `.nav` using [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) and select relevant item in `.nav2` by index using [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) and then trigger click event using [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

```js
$(".nav li").click(function(){
  console.log(".nav => "+$('a', this).text());
  $(".nav2 li").eq($(this).index()).click();
});
$(".nav2 li").click(function(){
  console.log(".nav2 => "+$('a', this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="nav2">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your idea. I get it now. I thought I will use each function

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it by single click event as follow**

**You need to give same class to the nav bar and then call the click event and add the function in that event**

```js
  $(".MyList li").click(function(){
  //Call Your Function here
  alert('Event Called')
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav MyList">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
<div class="nav2 MyList">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: I get error for this. There is an event of nav2. If I click nav, the nav2 will click. thanks for idea also